# type-bound custom ComboBox deriving from ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, custom-controls, type-bounds

I am supposed to create a custom ComboBox by deriving a class from ComboBox in my WinForms application. I have never done this before and not able to find many good example from Google.

I am required to derive a custom combobox so that I can make the custom combobox type-bound to a particular object.

This is what I have so far.

***CustomComboBox.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MAPClient {
    class MAPCodeComboBox : ComboBox {

    }
}
```

I have some specific questions:

1. Which methods do I need to override?
2. How do I use it in my VS2010 designer mode?

Comment: "Which methods do I need to override?" - well.... what does it need to do differently? Also, you should clarify whether this is winforms, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, etc...

Comment: If this is the first time you've done any work with custom controls, then you should maybe read up on it a bit? See [Developing Custom Windows Forms Controls with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx)

Comment: @John Saunders: Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Making it strongly type-bound is more work than you might expect (correctly wrapping and hiding both `DataSource` and `Items`) - is it really worth it?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: "is it really worth it?" -- NO. But still, I must do it! Please don't ask why!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I have the following for a custom type-bounded ComboBox. Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

***MAPComboBox.cs***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MAPClient {
    class MAPComboBox : ComboBox {
        private MAPCodeObjectCollection MAPCodeItemCollection = null;

        new public MAPCodeObjectCollection Items {
            // override
        }

        new public List<MAPCode> DataSource {
            // override
        }

        public MAPCodeComboBox() { }
    }
}
```

***MAPCodeObjectCollection.cs***

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MAPClient {
    class MAPCodeObjectCollection : ComboBox.ObjectCollection {
        public MAPCodeObjectCollection(ComboBox owner) : base(owner) { }

        new public int Add(object item) {
            // override
        }

        new public void Insert(int index, object item) {
            // override
        }
    }
}
```